# how can i make .msi product code(GUID) stable

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I have a work to automate the installation/un-installation of msi packages.
I build the packages and need to deploy them on application servers manually.
As a part of automating these things i am trying to deploy the packages from Build server to Application Servers.

Let me explain my question in simple words:
Suppose if I have a package (app-12.1) which is deployed on Application Server.
I built a new package (app-12.2), i need to uninstall app-12.1 and need to install app-12.2 on application server from build server remotely.

In order to do above task, i am trying to extract product code(GUID) of app-12.2 package, with that i am trying to uninstall app-12.1

**Problem:**
Product codes of app-12.1 and app-12.2 are different. As soon as i build new packages product code is changing by default.Due to that un-installation process is failing on application server.

while building the app-12.2 package how can i make sure product code(GUID) is STABLE.
so that i can use that product code for un-installation of app-12.1

Please provide me the tips, such that i can keep product code(GUID) same for all the versions.

Thanks
kiran

Comment: If they are the same product and can't live side-by-side, then the product code shouldn't be changing between 12.1 and 12.2. The code changes when the product can live side-by-side

Answer (score 3):

You want different product codes but the same *upgrade code*. If you keep the upgrade code the same between versions but change the product code, then the previous version will be uninstalled automatically during the installation of the new version.

The following link might be of some use: [What are Upgrade, Product and Package Codes used for?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pusu/archive/2009/06/10/understanding-msi.aspx)